# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with this code that's executing a prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql

Why am I getting a NullPointerException with this code that's executing a prepared statement?

```
 public ArrayList<BeanStaff> getLeaveStatus(ArrayList<String> name,String date) throws Exception
 {
    ArrayList<BeanStaff> lDetail = new ArrayList();
    String r = name.toString();
    Statement st  = null;
    DateFormat formatter = null;
    Date convertedDate = null;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
    java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(convertedDate.getTime());

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select Leave_Status from staff_leave_detail join employe on staff_leave_detail.Emp_ID = employe.Emp_ID where Leave_Start_Date=? and Emp_F_Name=?");
        ps.setDate(1,dt);
        ps.setString(2,r);
        ps.addBatch();
        if(r.equals(name.size()))
        {
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
        while(ps.getMoreResults())
        {
            rs  = ps.getResultSet();
        }
        while(rs.next())
        {
            BeanStaff sf = new BeanStaff();
            sf.setLeaveStatus(rs.getString("Leave_Status"));
            lDetail.add(sf);
        }
    }  
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.close();
        st.close();
    }
    return lDetail;
}
```

Comment: `but getting null pointer exception` - We are not mind readers. We don't know which statement is causing the Exception. Read your stack trace to find the statement with the problem. Then find the variable that is null. Then fix it so the variable is not null.

Comment: camickr: i am getting null in ps.getResultSet()..

Comment: user2495933, you'll make yourself and your colleagues much happier if you stick with a consistent code formatting style.

Comment: `st.close();` will also raise NPE as st is set to null and never changes (or used).

Answer (score 1):

You have this condition:

```
if(r.equals(name.size()))
```

That appears to be problematic since you earlier initialize `r` as:

```
String r = name.toString();
```

**How can size of an ArrayList ever be equal to the same ArrayList's `toString()`?**

I believe this condition is always failing (returning false) and your `ps.executeBatch()` never gets called.

Comment: anubhava, plz give me whole solution for above code as i m new in batch processing, thanks

Comment: I can help you finding your problems however I don't have any knowledge of your requirements OR your DB schema.

Comment: anubhava: i am trying to get the Leave status for all employees for  particular date and the query i ave written above is working accurate in database. But ps.execute() is returning null each time

Comment: That is fine but what exactly is this line doing `String r = name.toString();`?

Comment: anubhava:i am getting all employees in an arraylist name and String r is taking one employee at a time to get its leave status

Comment: In that case `String r = name.toString();` is totally wrong. You will need to run a loop iterating each element from your ArrayList. Please spare sometime learning the collection in Java.

Comment: anubhava: will u plz give me solution for above code bcz i m fresher and doing work in java as well as in batch processing first time.i will be really thankful to you,

Comment: See this tutorial on batch operations: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/ My advice to you is try to educate yourself on this.

Comment: anubhava: Thanku so much,i have read from this link previously but i m not getting the solution for how can i send each employee one by one....

Comment: As I suggested above you need run a loop like `for (String n: name) {...}` Inside loop replace `...` with your own code where `n` represent's each element in `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: anubhava: i have done this   : PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("Select Leave_Status from staff_leave_detail join employe on staff_leave_detail.Emp_ID = employe.Emp_ID where Leave_Start_Date=? and Emp_F_Name=?");
           for(String n:name){   
        ps.setDate(1,dt);
              ps.setString(2,n);
              ps.addBatch();
           }
               
              ps.execute();  // but this is taking null still

Comment: You need to edit your question and post your latest code then I can point you where it is failing. Please understand SO is not a forum for outsourcing your work. If you run into problems we shall help but you need to show efforts.